# Laravel insert multiple checkbox values into the database

Tags: laravel, checkbox, insert

I am trying to insert multiple values from multiple values checkbox also adding the dropmenus  values i need a way to post all these values
this the view code:

```
@extends('admin/main')
@section('title','|Add Section')
@section ('content')
{!!Form::open()!!}
{{Form::label('program','Program')}}
<br>
{{ Form::select('program', ['CMSE'=>'CMSE','CMPE'=>'CMPE','BLGM'=>'BLGM'], 'CMPE',['class'=>'selectpicker']) }}

<br>
{{Form::label('year','Year')}}
<br>

{{ Form::selectrange('year  ',2018,2019,null,['class'=>'selectpicker'])}}
<br>
{{Form::label('semester','Semester')}}
<br>

{{ Form::select('smester', ['fall'=>'fall','spring'=>'spring','summer'=>'summer'], 'CMPE',['class'=>'selectpicker','id'=>'program']) }}

<br>
<br>
    <div class="col-md-8" id="courses">
                <h3 align="center">Computer Engineering courses</h3>
                <br>
                <form>
                @foreach ($courses as $course)
                 <div class="form-check">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sections[]" value="{{$course->courseid}}"> <span class="label-text"><span style="color:#ea9c9b">{{$course->courseid}}</span>  {{$course->title}}</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                @endforeach

<form>          
{{Form::submit('Add Sections',['class'=>'btn btn-success','id'=>'addSections'])}}

{!!Form::close()!!}
        </div>
```

Comment: what is your problem ? and what you have tried ?

Comment: Can you explain your problem more pls

Comment: my problem is when i am tring to insert the checked value into the database it gives me error in the controller because of using foreach loop public function iwant to deal with the array sections                            addSection(Request $request)
{
 $sec=$request->sections;
 $semester=$request->semester;
 $year=$request->year;
 $instructor=$request->instructor;
 @foreach($sec as $secs){
         $section=new section;
        $section->course_id=$secs;  $section->instructor_id=$instructor;
 $section->semester=$semester;
 $section->year=$year;
 $sec}tion->save;
}
@endforeacch